# Database creation on start up

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, identity

I am trying to initialize the database on first startup to create the database tables needed for identity.net. So then FluentMigrator can run without errors saying the tables don't exist.

So far in Global.aspx I have:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

Migrator.Runner.MigrateToLatest();
```

but this doesn't seem to create the tables?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think newing up the `DbContext` is enough to trigger the initializer. Try to access something on the `DbContext`...

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
context.Users.Count();
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked a treat, sorry for late response.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help. Just realized `ToList()` might have been a bad choice if there is data in the table. Try something like `Count()` or anything else that's quick and doesn't return a pile of data.